# Explicit Type Argument Kotlin and RxJava

Tags: rx-java, kotlin

Is this the only possible way of using RxJava's `compose` with `ThreadTransformer` in Kotlin? I just don't like the `<MyType>` part in `compose` function. Is it possible to omit it?

```
  override fun call(): Observable<MyType> {
    return Observable.just(getData())
        .compose(threadTransformer.applySchedulers<MyType>())
  }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Observable.compose` is a workaround for the lack of extension functions in Java. There is no need to use `Observable.compose` in Kotlin because it supports extension functions out of the box:

```
// default schedulers
fun <T> Observable<T>.applySchedulers(): Observable<T> {
  return subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}

// custom transformer
fun <T> Observable<T>.applySchedulers(transformer: ThreadTransformer): Observable<T> {
  return compose(transformer.applySchedulers<T>())
}

override fun call(): Observable<MyType> {
  return Observable.just(getData()).applySchedulers()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on Vladimir Mironov's answer. Extend this to your needs:

```
//Observable
fun <T> Observable<T>.applyIoScheduler() = applyScheduler(Schedulers.io())
fun <T> Observable<T>.applyComputationScheduler() = applyScheduler(Schedulers.computation())
private fun <T> Observable<T>.applyScheduler(scheduler: Scheduler) =
                subscribeOn(scheduler).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

//Single
fun <T> Single<T>.applyIoScheduler() = applyScheduler(Schedulers.io())
fun <T> Single<T>.applyComputationScheduler() = applyScheduler(Schedulers.computation())
private fun <T> Single<T>.applyScheduler(scheduler: Scheduler) =
            subscribeOn(scheduler).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

//Completable
//..
```